# SQL ROW_NUMBER with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I need to use ROW_NUMBER() in the following Query to return rows 5 to 10 of the result. Can anyone please show me what I need to do? I've been trying to no avail. If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   villa_data 
       INNER JOIN villa_prices 
         ON villa_prices.starRating = villa_data.starRating 
WHERE  villa_data.capacity >= 3 
       AND villa_data.bedrooms >= 1 
       AND villa_prices.period = 'lowSeason' 
ORDER  BY villa_prices.price, 
          villa_data.bedrooms, 
          villa_data.capacity
```

Comment: This looks a little homework-y - what have you *tried*? Did it result in an error? "Wrong" results? You're *apparently* already aware that `ROW_NUMBER` is the correct function to perform paging...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever he has provided the query. Sorry but just want to be reasonable. It is a valid question.

Answer (score 11):

You need to stick it in a table expression to filter on `ROW_NUMBER`. You won't be able to use `*` as it will complain about the column name `starRating` appearing more than once so will need to list out the required columns explicitly. This is better practice anyway.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT /*TODO: List column names*/
       ROW_NUMBER() 
          OVER (ORDER BY villa_prices.price, 
                         villa_data.bedrooms, 
                         villa_data.capacity) AS RN
FROM   villa_data 
       INNER JOIN villa_prices 
         ON villa_prices.starRating = villa_data.starRating 
WHERE  villa_data.capacity >= 3 
       AND villa_data.bedrooms >= 1 
       AND villa_prices.period = 'lowSeason' 

)
SELECT /*TODO: List column names*/
FROM CTE
WHERE RN BETWEEN 5 AND 10
ORDER BY RN
```

Comment: Actually you could use * : [[ SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...) AS [RN], * FROM ...]]

Comment: @Cristi - The reason they can't use `*` is because the column name `starRating` appears in both tables and column names in CTEs must be unique.

Comment: oops, did not pay attention to that, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a with clause. Please try the following

```
WITH t AS
(
SELECT villa_data.starRating, 
   villa_data.capacity,
   villa_data.bedrooms,
   villa_prices.period,
   villa_prices.price,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY villa_prices.price, 
      villa_data.bedrooms, 
      villa_data.capacity ) AS 'RowNumber'
FROM   villa_data 
   INNER JOIN villa_prices
     ON villa_prices.starRating = villa_data.starRating 
WHERE  villa_data.capacity >= 3 
   AND villa_data.bedrooms >= 1 
   AND villa_prices.period = 'lowSeason' 
)
SELECT * 
FROM t 
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 5 AND 10;
```

Comment: This one brings back a result. Thanks! I have a question... Can I execute this from ASP? I've tried adding it to my page code with a standard "oDatabase.SQL = "WITH t AS (SELECT..." but its not returning any rows. Am I missing something? Apologies if this is a stupid question

Comment: @JasonEyebe Sorry, but I'm not familiar with ASP at all.